# getting error " There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'State'."

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am getting the following error: "There is no ViewData item of type `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` that has the key `State`."

How can I solve this error, what am I doing wrong?

```
<div class="form-group">                        
    <label for="State">State</label>
    @Html.DropDownList("State", ViewBag.State as SelectList, "---Select State----")
</div>

public void state_bind()
{
    DataSet ds = empDB.getstate();
    List<SelectListItem> statelist = new List<SelectListItem>();

    foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
        statelist.Add(new SelectListItem { 
            Text=dr["Name"].ToString(), 
            Value=dr["ID"].ToString()
        });
    }

    ViewBag.State = statelist;
}
```

Comment: Where are you calling for the method state_bind? ViewBag should be set before the view is rendered, in the actionmethod. Otherwise everything seems correct.

Comment: still getting error

Comment: Hi lalit, did you try below solution?

Comment: tried below solution but it does'nt work?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use ViewBag.State as below

HTML

```
 @Html.DropDownList("State", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.State, "Select State", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Answer (score -1):

used below html

HTML :

```
  <div class="form-group">                         
    <label for="State">State</label>  
  @Html.DropDownList("State", null, "--  Select  --", new { @class = "" })

</div>
```